# react js access import enum values into component class instead of static method

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a reactjs app where I am importing an enum of values like so

import MyValues from './MyValueList'

which contains

export default : {
test1: 0,
test2: 1,
test3:3,
}

In my react component class in any method like

```
getValue() {

  const test = MyValues.test1 // this return nothing, in my debug WATCH console, it is undefined
  return test
}
```

however when I used a static method

```
static getStaticValue() {
  return MyValues.test1
}
```

this works in my method but not efficient, that means I will have to write a static method for each enum value.

How can I get the enum value without static methods? Is there a better method to get extract the value from the imported file.

Thanks

Comment: `getValue()` in your example returns nothing, it initialized a variable `test` that it then doesn't use any further. Also where are you using `getValue()`? I can't reproduce your issue. See this codesandbox I created from what you described: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-lake-hcgzo?file=/src/App.js . It works perfectly with or without a static method. I also don't see any reason why this should make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using a method or static method doesn't make any difference whatsoever to your use-case. The bug must lay elsewhere in your logic. You can read more about static methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).

Possible issues:

- Are you calling `getMethod()`?
- Is `getMethod()` called somewhere different than the static method? This shouldn't really matter bug it's useful when debugging.
- Are you calling it correctly? `this.getMethod()`

I'd add a console log `getMethod()` for your import and see what values you're getting, or if it's running at all.